# SWIG Python bindings to native code not working with OpenCV 2.1

Tags: python, c, opencv, swig, ctypes

I have an OpenCV project mixing Python and C. After changing to OpenCV 2.1, my calls to C code are not working any more, probably because OpenCV is no more using SWIG bindings.

From Python, I was used to call a C function with the following prototype:

```
int fast_support_transform(CvMat * I, CvMat * N,...);
```

Now, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: in method 'fast_support_transform', argument 1 of type 'CvMat *'
```

The C code is from a library created by me that uses SWIG to produces the Python interface. I'm not sure, but I think OpenCV is using ctypes now and this code is unable to send a CvMat pointer to my native code.

Do you know about a fast fix to this problem? Any tips are welcome.

**UPDATE**: Visitors, note this question is **outdated**. Python support in OpenCV is very mature now. `CvMat` is being represented as a Numpy array by default now.

Comment: Try converting `cvMat`s to `cvArr`s and then using the cvArr * as the arguments?  cvMat is derived from cvArr. So, once you get the cvArr pointer, you could ten convert it back to cvMat and use it. Or the other option will be to go back to the last working version of OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

For work I once wrapped Tesseract (OCR software) using Cython which is a very Python-esque language.  You write a mostly-python program which gets compiled into a full-on binary python module.  In your .pyx file you can import C/C++ files/libraries instantiate objects, call functions, etc.

http://www.cython.org/

You could define a small Cython project and do something like:

```
#make sure Cython knows about a CvMat
cdef extern from "opencv2/modules/core/include/opencv2/types_c.h":
    ctypedef struct CvMat

#import your fast_support_transform
cdef extern from "my_fast_support_transform_file.h":
    int fast_support_transform(CvMat * I, CvMat * N, ...)

#this bit is the glue code between Python and C
def my_fast_support_transform(CvMat * I, CvMat * N, ...)
    return fast_support_transform(CvMat * I, CvMat * N, ...)
```

You'll also need a distutils/Cython build file that looks something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("wrapped_support_transform", ["wrapped_support_transform.pyx"])]
)
```

The Cython website has an excellent tutorial to making your first Cython project:
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html